# Sony Camera Remote API - ContentFile URI explicitness

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I have an application where i can save Pictures from a Sony Camera via the Remote API.
Now i wonder if the long URI of a file

e.g. `image:content?contentId=index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000094-00000B2D_148_1_1000`

is completely unique?

Can i get the same URI when i change the time in camera/ use another camera/ use another sd card (change sdcard or save to sdcard 2 instead of 1)
.
 Or is it just unique in one camera and i can clearyl assign it by saving camera UUID to each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that getting the same image URI on different cameras would not be possible. As it states on page 195 of the documentation the camera remote API uses standard RFC 3986 to define it's URI structure:

> In Camera Remote API, standard URI structure, as defined by RFC 3986,
>   is used for representing device's resources. Schemes are used to refer
>   to device resources.

This structure seeks to define independant URI's so it should be very unlikely that you will ever get the same URI between cameras but as you mentioned there are situations which may cause 2 cameras to produce the same URI. Please keep that in mind if you are building a system that depends on the URI's being unique

Comment: Hi Kilian. Actually I just found out this morning that uniqueness of uri's cannot be guaranteed. It is unlikely, but it seems that if you are creating a system that will break if they are not unique then it won't work. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: One more question to be sure i understand it right. Same URI can only  happen between cameras? So one camera cannot create the same URI twice?